# Return value from button click made in RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created a chat app by using `RecyclerView`.

If one of the users in the chat clicks on some button, the following message is sent in the chat:

[image]

This message contains a string and 2 `buttons` that were created in my `RecyclerView`.

Now, I had like to do some action based on if the second users click `confirm` or `decline`.

How can I set a click listener to these buttons?

The buttons were created inside the `RecycelerView` however I had like that once a user clicked Confirm it will perform an action in the class that is outside the adapter where all my parameters are.

How can I like to return a value from the adapter? Something like if a user clicked `Confirm`, it will return 1 to the outer class and then I will run some code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save these values in the sharePreference then retrieve and check them in the outer class then perform needed actions.

Answer (score 0):

create interface like

```
interface onConfirmClicked{
```

fun onConfirmed(value:Boolean)
}

implement this into your class and send it to your adapter

```
 class A : onConfirmClicked{

ovveride fun onConfirmed(value: Boolean){
//do what you want here
}

adapter.setOnConfirmClicked(this)

}
```

into your adapter in the confirm button clickLisnter  call this

```
onConfirmClickListner.onConfirmed(true)
```

Comment: you can to refer to this also https://android.jlelse.eu/click-listener-for-recyclerview-adapter-2d17a6f6f6c9